# One button that has multiple function - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, switch-statement

I am making an **action button** that implements different function each time the button is pressed. When I clicked once, the map changes to **satellite** and when i clicked it again, it changes to **standard** and when i clicked it again, it changes to **hybrid** and when i clicked it again, it goes back to **satellite**.

This is my code. Please let me know where did I do wrong.

```
    @IBAction func changeLayout(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    switch (sender.anyObject()) {
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
    default:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.hybrid
    }

}
```

The error that I got says:

Expression pattern of type 'Int' cannot match values of type 'Any?' ViewController.swift

Comment: "Please let me know where did I do wrong." In order to do that, you need to tell _us_ what's happening.

Comment: You are not testing the _current_ `mapView.mapType` so you don't know what the _new_ `mapType` should be!

Comment: opps! totally forgotten to put my error. thanks for reminding me. i edited the post

Comment: Why you do you think you can say `anyObject()` to the `sender`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume the method is called by pressing an UIButton? If so, you can replace `AnyObject` with `UIButton`. Then you can use the UIButton's `tag` property to check the current state.

```
@IBAction func changeLayout(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.tag += 1
    if sender.tag > 2 { sender.tag = 0 }

    switch sender.tag { 
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = .satellite
    case 2:
        mapView.mapType = .hybrid
    default:
        mapView.mapType = .standard
    }
}
```

And to keep things 'Swiftly', you can remove the parentheses around the switch value as well as the enum's type. ;)

Comment: you save me so much time from googling and finding different ways of doing it. Thank you kind sir!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it would just be to switch the enum using the raw value.

```
@IBAction func changeLayout(_ sender: UIButton) {

    mapView.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: (mapView.mapType.rawValue + 1) % 2 )
}
```

This assumes the raw values you want are 0,1,2 (which I think they are)